# What is the difference with PS4 Kingdom Hearts 2.8 Limited Edition and Normal Edition?

Tags: ps4, version-differences, kingdom-hearts

What are the differences between the 2 versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on what I have seen the only difference is an included pin

See [here](https://store.na.square-enix.com/product/289787/kingdom-hearts-hd-28-final-chapter-prologue-limited-edition-ps4)

> The KINGDOM HEARTS HD 2.8 FINAL CHAPTER PROLOGUE LIMITED EDITION  **includes an exclusive official Disney collector's pin while supplies last.**

And [here](http://gematsu.com/2016/10/kingdom-hearts-hd-2-8-limited-edition-announced)

> The limited edition includes an official Disney collector’s pin featuring Sora and Mickey, as well as limited edition packaging.

Comment: So this pin just replaces the in-game logo of Final Chapter Prologue with Sora and Mickey but nothing changed with the Final Chapter Prologue if I'm correct?

Comment: @Nova I don't think it changes anything in-game, just adds a pin to the packaging

Answer (score 3):

The only difference is that the Limited Edition comes with an [exclusive pin](https://store.na.square-enix.com/product/289787/kingdom-hearts-hd-28-final-chapter-prologue-limited-edition-ps4), while supplies last.